# WordPress File Access Permission

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, file-permissions

I am trying to upload an image to set a background image for my theme, but I get this error:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?”

I tried to change the access permissions with the help of these blogs:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/setting-permissions-for-wordpress
2. https://gist.github.com/Adirael/3383404

But nothing has helped me, and now I also get a 500 error page.

I'm stuck here, can anybody help?

-----------Comment-----------
[Output Image for ps -ef| grep httpd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH2IM.png)

I executed this command

```
find . type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

and the 500 error page is not being displayed now. I am able to view my web page. But I am still unable to upload a background image. (same error appears "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?")

Comment: Hello, you need to give write permissions on the folder wp-content/uploads/ , check this article from WP. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Hi @josedasilva I tried changing the access permissions. Here are the screenshots for the currently set permissions,

Answer (score 1):

The following command will fix your issue

```
sudo chmod -R 777 wp-contents/uploads/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bitnami Lamp then run the following commands in your SSH terminal:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
sudo chmod 440 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/wp-config.php
sudo chmod 440 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/.htaccess
```

and if you're using Bitnami WordPress then run the following commands in your SSH terminal:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chmod 440 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
sudo chmod 440 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/.htaccess
```

The recommended permissions are:

1. Directories: 775
2. Files: 640
3. wp-config.php and.htacess: 440

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is already solved, but can help other users with similar issues.

I made a Shell Script on Debian10 to solve permissions issues.
After running it, I make the folder accesible on the Apache2.conf too (WordPress can't Upgrade or Upload Media if not)

What it does:

1. Set new Owner on all Files and (Sub)Directories ( user:group )
2. Set Permissions: 755 to Directories and 644 to Files
3. wp-config.php : Preventing world access for "wp-config.php", leaving it accesible to WordPress (660)
4. Allow WordPress to manage the "wp-content" (Directories to 755 & Files to 664)
5. Privatize "wp-content" (Set 755)

Link:
https://github.com/ieselisra/wordpress_fix_permissions_debian10/